# Framework Errors in Parse App ParseFacebookUtils

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-framework, parsefacebookutils

I updated the Parse Framework to the newest version in my app, and now I am getting a TON of errors in my app, mostly Framework related:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAccessToken", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookUtils.o)
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookUtils.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "std::string::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::find_first_not_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
```

I have confirmed that the Framework is added, so I'm not sure what the error is being caused by.

Comment: did you got fix? i am also getting that issue. please help me out for fixing it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are using CocoaPods or not, but if so, I ran into the same issue today when updating. From what it appears, 'Facebook-iOS-SDK' and 'ParseFacebookUtils' was removed from the most recent update. Without going to in depth in your errors, it appears as though linker errors are occurring. In my Podfile, I simply added:

```
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
```

If not using CocoaPods, it may help to make sure those two libraries are within your source code, clean, and rebuild.

Comment: Issue with mine was I had the linker flag -ObjC.  Once I removed it, it worked fine.

Comment: The 'Facebook-iOS-SDK' and 'ParseFacebookUtils' pods are now deprecated. See upgrade guide for Facebook iOS SDK v 4.1.0 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x

Comment: @neverbendeasy is right. You can checkout the updated pods as [ParseFacebookUtilsV4](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/1.7.2.2/) and [FBSDKCoreKit](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FBSDKCoreKit/4.1.0/)